# php time based image wont change right

Tags: php

I made a page with images that are time based so they change at a specific time. Now i got it all working and stuff but it doesnt show the correct image at the right time it should be like this:

- morning = 6.00/12.00
- afternoon = 12.00/18.00
- evening = 18.00/00.00
- night = 00.00/6.00

but for example it shows the night at 13.00 now. what did i do wrong here?

**php**

```
 <?php
      date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
      
    function getTime() {
    
    
        $time = date('h:i');
        $style = "";
    
        if ($time >= 6 && $time < 12) {
            $style = $style . "morning";
            define("TIME", "Goodmorning!");
        }
        elseif($time >= 12 && $time < 18){
            $style = $style . "afternoon";
            define("TIME", "Goodafternoon!");
        }
        elseif($time >= 18 && $time == 0){
            $style = $style . "evening";
            define("TIME", "Goodevening!");
        }
        else {
            $style = $style . "night";
            define("TIME", "Goodnight!");
        }
    
        echo $style;
    }
    
    getTime();
    ?>
```

**html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="eng">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
       <title>PHP time based</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class= "text">
        <div id="Time" class="<?php getTime(); ?>">
            <h1><?php echo TIME; ?></h1>
            <h1><?php echo "it is now " . date("h:i"); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

**css**

```
  body{
        padding: 0%;
        margin: 0%;
        color: white;
        height: 700px;
    }
    
    .text{
        margin-top: auto;
        text-align: center;
        top: 50%;
        bottom: 50%;
    }
    
    .morning{
        background: url("images/morning.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
        height: 700px;
    }
    
    .afternoon{
        background: url("images/afternoon.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
        height: 700px;
    }
    
    .evening{
        background: url("images/evening.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
        height: 700px;
    }
    
    .night{
        background: url("images/night.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
        height: 700px;
    }
```

SO it should show an text like :

> goodafternoon, it is now 13.45

and have a different image and text based on the time

Comment: Use `date('G')` instead of `date('h:i')`

Comment: If I use that the images still wont show at the right time

Comment: `h` return 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros. `i` returns minutes with leading zeros. `h:i` returns a non-numeric string (eg: '01:32'), that you're trying to compare to an integer.

Comment: so there is no possible way to do it like this?

Comment: `G` or `H` really should work in your case.

Comment: but with g/h it doesnt show the minutes? there is no way to do it with the minutes included?

Comment: Why would minutes matter? Your conditions don't deal with minutes.

Comment: I would like to show the minutes and the hour but you say i cant do this right now?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up two things. The code in your question *does not show the date*. So why would minutes matter for your `getTime` function?

Comment: "showing" is different than "comparing".

Comment: I dont mean to show the date but something like this : goodafternoon, it is now 13.45 like that. but now the code shows the wrong images

Comment: As I suspected, you do that later in the code somewhere. Has nothing to do with the question, though.

Comment: i dont get it anymore

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand :) Here's a simplified example: https://3v4l.org/GsDaH Minutes don't matter inside your function. Nothing stops you from printing the current time elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the example but it will only show the "goodnight", i add a bit more of my code btw

Comment: Another thing, `$hour >= 18 && $hour == 0` doesn't make sens. if $hour is greater than 18, it couldn't be equals to 0.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the asker wants to get the time in the format described, mine the hour from it to perform some logic and display it. We can criticize this code for its problems, but it does not make sense if you ask me. This is clearly a beginner, who tried his/her best to implement something and missed some details. Encouragement is what he/she needs from our part. We need to show him/her how close this code was to the intended, rather than pointing out how much he/she does not know. We ultimately want to solve problems, I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few fixes here and there. First, the way you get the time, afternoon times are shown as 04:59 instead of 16:59, so it's something AM/PM. This caused a major problem. Also, there were issues with the logic. Overall, you were pretty close to the solution, you just missed a few little details. This works for me:

```
 <?php
      date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");

    function getTime() {


        $rawTime = explode(" ", date('h:i A'));
        $time = $rawTime[0];
        if (($rawTime[1] === "PM") && ($time !== "00:00")) {
            $temp = explode(":", $time);
            $temp[0] = ((int)$temp[0]) + 12;
            $time = implode(":", $temp);
        }
        $style = "";
    
        if (($time >= "06:00") && ($time < "12:00")) {
            $style = $style . "morning";
            define("TIME", "Goodmorning!");
        }
        else if(($time >= "12:00") && ($time < "18:00")){
            $style = $style . "afternoon";
            define("TIME", "Goodafternoon!");
        }
        else if(($time >= "18:00") && ($time < "24:00")){
            $style = $style . "evening";
            define("TIME", "Goodevening!");
        }
        else {
            $style = $style . "night";
            define("TIME", "Goodnight!");
        }
    
        echo "Good {$style}, it is now {$time}";
        return $time;
    }
    
    getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this and showing an example of it, really appreciate it

Comment: To add different images to it I need to use an HTML? and just make a div with 4 different images src right and just switch between them

Comment: @ptrique you are welcome! Yes, you need to do some HTML stuff in order to display it correctly in the browser. I recommend the separation between your representation and the logic with which you compute, that will help you a lot to write more general-purpose, portable and reusable code. For the time being I did not overcomplicate my answer with that, as the first thing is to make sure that you have some success with your current effort. But, after studying the difference between the code that did not work and the code which works, maybe a refactoring would be a good idea.

Comment: sorry if im bothering you, but i dont get how to make it in the html so the images change. i made a div with the 4 images in it but it shows all 4 images now which is logic because they are all in the div but i dont get how to make it work so it only show 1 at a time.I just started php and i really dont get much of it at this point

Comment: @ptrique you need to hide 3 of the images. For this purpose, you can create a CSS class like ```.invisible {display: none}``` and you can type your images such as ```<img src="somesource" <?php echo somefunction() ? 'class="invisible"' : ""; ?>>```. It's not very difficult. If you ask a question and link it here about this specific topic, then I'm happy to answer it. This second problem is more about UI issues, so it belongs to a separate question.

Comment: @ptrique btw, I do not feel bothered. We all were beginners at some point and I know how difficult it is to figure out everything when there is not much experience to rely on. Back in the day things were much less documented on the internet and I had to figure out everything by myself. It was not a nice experience, for sure :)

Comment: i made a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66230640/14541933 i dont know if it is very clear to understand what i mean to do

Comment: `$time >= "18:00"` is an invalid use of the `>=` operator. The operants are strings, not numbers.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Kindly read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php. In PHP you can compare strings withour a problem via >=.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that. But your strings are converted to numbers to do the comparison. So it happens to work for full hours, because PHP happens to ignore the `:00` bit, but that's more luck than anything else. It also will not work correctly if you try `"18:45" > "18:15"`, that will return `FALSE`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware and in our case we have two digit numbers and two digit minutes, so alphabetical comparison will be just what we need. Note that AM/PM was handled by adding 12 to the hour if it was PM, so this will work well with alphabetic comparisons.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware have you tried your input? It yields 1 to me, which is truey.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware try putting the following: ```<?php echo ("18:45" > "18:15");``` into a file called foo.php and execute it in the terminal/cmd via ```php foo.php```. It yields 1 to me which, converted to boolean is true. So it works.

Comment: Oke, I tested it, and I was wrong, `"18:45" > "18:15"` returns `TRUE`, because the `4` is further in the ASCII table than `1`. I still think one shouldn't do this, but that's just a personal opinion.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, you are right. This provably works and I have used this approach when it was helpful over the years. However, if you do not like it, you can use some other approach, like using hour and minute as separate numbers. It will be a longer condition in terms of source-code, but, in some cases it is quicker, depending on the exact situation.

Comment: @ptrique answered the other question.

Comment: @LajosArpad can i ask one more question to you?

Comment: @ptrique yes, of course. You may ask it in the comment section, or as a separate question, depending on how related it is to this one.

Comment: it isnt really a hard question i guess so, but i tried changing the p element in my css so the text+time would be bigger etc but it doesnt work

Comment: @LajosArpad i tried to google it and stuff but am not able to find a answer, I also tried to do the styling on the body instead of the p element itself but it dont want to work out

Comment: @ptrique I recommend asking a new question where you would define the style you would like to display and show how you tried to achieve it. You could link that question here as well. I would be happy to help.

Comment: @LajosArpad here is the new question i made https://stackoverflow.com/q/66258200/14541933