# php change image on time

Tags: php, html, css

I made a post about this: [php time based image wont change right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66224206/14541933) right now i got the time working but still need the 4 images to change correctly.

i made a div with the 4 images in it but now the images need to change on specific times. i gave all the images the class"images" and set the display to none in the css however the images will still show up.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
   <title>PHP time based page</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
function getTime() {
    $Time = explode(" ", date('h:i A'));
    $time = $Time[0];
    if (($Time[1] === "PM") && ($time !== "00:00")) {
        $temp = explode(":", $time);
        $temp[0] = ((int)$temp[0]) + 12;
        $time = implode(":", $temp);
    }
    $Moment = "";

    if (($time >= "06:00") && ($time < "12:00")) {
        $Moment = $Moment . "morning";
        define("TIME", "Goodmorning!");
    }
    else if(($time >= "12:00") && ($time < "18:00")){
        $Moment = $Moment . "afternoon";
        define("TIME", "Goodafternoon!");
    }
    else if(($time >= "18:00") && ($time < "24:00")){
        $Moment = $Moment . "evening";
        define("TIME", "Goodevening!");
    }
    else {
        $Moment = $Moment . "night";
        define("TIME", "Goodnight!");
    }

    return ["moment" => $Moment, "time" => $time];
}

function getGreeting() {
    return "Good ".getTime()["moment"].", it is now ".getTime()["time"];
}

$images = [
    "morning",
    "afternoon",
    "evening",
    "night"
];
?>

<p><?php echo getGreeting(); ?></p>
<div class="images">
    <?php
    $moment = getTime()["moment"]; 
    ?>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $moment; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
 body{
        padding: 0%;
        margin: 0%;
        color: white;
        height: 700px;
    }
    
    .invisible{
    display: none;
}
```

so if this is the page, the text should be something like this and the images need to change
[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rename the images class to invisible to reflect what it is supposed to do better, like

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

Let's create a PHP array with the times:

```
$images = [
    "morning",
    "afternoon",
    "evening",
    "night"
];
```

Make sure that `getTime` returns the text and only the text:

```
function getTime() {
    //Don't change the lines above the return statement
    return $Moment;
}
```

This is how you can operate:

```
<div class="images">
    <?php
    $moment = getTime(); // Unfortunately getTime does some echoing, you will need to refactor it to separate representation from computation
    ?>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $moment; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
</div>
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
   <title>PHP time based page</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
function getTime() {
    //Don't change the lines above the return statement
    return $Moment;
}
$images = [
    "morning",
    "afternoon",
    "evening",
    "night"
];
?>
<div class="images">
    <?php
    $moment = getTime(); // Unfortunately getTime does some echoing, you will need to refactor it to separate representation from computation
    ?>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $moment; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
</div>


 </body>
</html>
```

EDIT

There are problems with getTime. We need to refactor it, as:

```
function getTime() {
    $Time = explode(" ", date('h:i A'));
    $time = $Time[0];
    if (($Time[1] === "PM") && ($time !== "00:00")) {
        $temp = explode(":", $time);
        $temp[0] = ((int)$temp[0]) + 12;
        $time = implode(":", $temp);
    }
    $Moment = "";

    if (($time >= "06:00") && ($time < "12:00")) {
        $Moment = $Moment . "morning";
        define("TIME", "Goodmorning!");
    }
    else if(($time >= "12:00") && ($time < "18:00")){
        $Moment = $Moment . "afternoon";
        define("TIME", "Goodafternoon!");
    }
    else if(($time >= "18:00") && ($time < "24:00")){
        $Moment = $Moment . "evening";
        define("TIME", "Goodevening!");
    }
    else {
        $Moment = $Moment . "night";
        define("TIME", "Goodnight!");
    }

    return $Moment;
}
```

EDIT2

Since the echo is no longer part of `getTime`, let's implement something instead:

```
function getGreeting() {
    return "Good ".getTime().", it is now {$time}";
}
```

and you can `echo` it as

```
echo getGreeting();
```

EDIT3

We need both time and greeting, doing further improvement:

```
function getTime() {
    $Time = explode(" ", date('h:i A'));
    $time = $Time[0];
    if (($Time[1] === "PM") && ($time !== "00:00")) {
        $temp = explode(":", $time);
        $temp[0] = ((int)$temp[0]) + 12;
        $time = implode(":", $temp);
    }
    $Moment = "";

    if (($time >= "06:00") && ($time < "12:00")) {
        $Moment = $Moment . "morning";
        define("TIME", "Goodmorning!");
    }
    else if(($time >= "12:00") && ($time < "18:00")){
        $Moment = $Moment . "afternoon";
        define("TIME", "Goodafternoon!");
    }
    else if(($time >= "18:00") && ($time < "24:00")){
        $Moment = $Moment . "evening";
        define("TIME", "Goodevening!");
    }
    else {
        $Moment = $Moment . "night";
        define("TIME", "Goodnight!");
    }

    return ["moment => "$Moment, "time" => $time];
}
```

Change `getGreeting` to

```
function getGreeting() {
    return "Good ".getTime()["moment"].", it is now ".getTime()["time"];
}
```

and change your images div to

```
<div class="images">
    <?php
    $moment = getTime()["moment"]; // Unfortunately getTime does some echoing, you will need to refactor it to separate representation from computation
    ?>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $moment; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
</div>
```

EDIT4

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
   <title>PHP time based page</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
function getTime() {
    $Time = explode(" ", date('h:i A'));
    $time = $Time[0];
    if (($Time[1] === "PM") && ($time !== "00:00")) {
        $temp = explode(":", $time);
        $temp[0] = ((int)$temp[0]) + 12;
        $time = implode(":", $temp);
    }
    $Moment = "";

    if (($time >= "06:00") && ($time < "12:00")) {
        $Moment = $Moment . "morning";
        define("TIME", "Goodmorning!");
    }
    else if(($time >= "12:00") && ($time < "18:00")){
        $Moment = $Moment . "afternoon";
        define("TIME", "Goodafternoon!");
    }
    else if(($time >= "18:00") && ($time < "24:00")){
        $Moment = $Moment . "evening";
        define("TIME", "Goodevening!");
    }
    else {
        $Moment = $Moment . "night";
        define("TIME", "Goodnight!");
    }

    return ["moment" => $Moment, "time" => $time];
}

function getGreeting() {
    return "Good ".getTime()["moment"].", it is now ".getTime()["time"];
}

$images = [
    "morning",
    "afternoon",
    "evening",
    "night"
];
?>

<p><?php echo getGreeting(); ?></p>
<div class="images">
    <?php
    $moment = getTime()["moment"]; 
    ?>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $moment; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ptrique this is where the problem is reproduced: https://jsfiddle.net/jhe35xyv/. By removing ```color:white;``` the paragraph becomes visible: https://jsfiddle.net/jhe35xyv/1/

Comment: @ptrique found out what your issue is. You have a color: white rule which converts the text color to white, which is the exact color of the background.

Comment: whenever i change the color to black or any other color than white it also doesnt show up?

Comment: @ptrique the thing to understand is that there are two colors you can work with: background-color and color. background-color is the color of the background, while color is the color of the foreground, i.e., your text, for example. If background-color and color are the same, then you will not see the text you have. So, it is important to keep these different.

Comment: @ptrique with other words: You will not see white characters on a white backround. If you have a white-colored pen and write with it on a white-colored paper, your writing will not be seen.

Comment: i have a black background color now and a white color, i think something is wrong with the linking of my css because it doesnt change anyting at this moment

Comment: @ptrique no, it's just your browser cache. Your browser, to avoid having to download your CSS each time you load the page, saves the file temporarily and assumes that it does not change in the meantime. You can empty your cache, but for the purpose of this discussion, I kindly ask you to load the page using a different browser, or in incognito mode to avoid the browser cache. Afterwards I recommend reading about browser cache, modern browsers support clearing the cache, that is, removing the temporary files from it.

Comment: oh i see, i inspected the page and the old css stuff was still in it like you said. i can just change the styling of the text by using p{} in the css right

Comment: @ptrique yes, you link your css correctly, it's just not manifesting in your browser yet because the browser assumes for a while that the file is unchanged. The reason for this is that this way the browser will have much less work to do (as well as the server), minimalizing communication.