# Styling on element wont change

Tags: php, html, css

I've made a page where the images shown change time-based. On the page there is a text which says goodmorning/afternoon/evening/night and then the time is displayed next to it.

Now I want to change the position of the time so it will be at the middle of the page, however, the text doesn't move when I try to add a styling on it using CSS.

I tried doing a styling on the `p` element itself like the margin and also setting the position to relative  but nothing seems to work. I also tried to do the styling on the body but same as the `p` element it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site2.css">
       <title>PHP time based page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Brussels");
    function getTime() {
        $Time = explode(" ", date('h:i A'));
        $time = $Time[0];
        if (($Time[1] === "PM") && ($time !== "00:00")) {
            $temp = explode(":", $time);
            $temp[0] = ((int)$temp[0]) + 12;
            $time = implode(":", $temp);
        }
        $Moment = "";
    
        if (($time >= "06:00") && ($time < "12:00")) {
            $Moment = $Moment . "morning";
            define("TIME", "Goodmorning!");
        }
        else if(($time >= "12:00") && ($time < "18:00")){
            $Moment = $Moment . "afternoon";
            define("TIME", "Goodafternoon!");
        }
        else if(($time >= "18:00") && ($time < "24:00")){
            $Moment = $Moment . "evening";
            define("TIME", "Goodevening!");
        }
        else {
            $Moment = $Moment . "night";
            define("TIME", "Goodnight!");
        }
    
        return ["moment" => $Moment, "time" => $time];
    }
    
    function getGreeting() {
        return "Good".getTime()["moment"].", It is now ".getTime()["time"];
    }
    
    $images = [
        "morning",
        "afternoon",
        "evening",
        "night"
    ];
    ?>
    
    <p><?php echo getGreeting(); ?></p>
    <div class="images">
        <?php
        $moment = getTime()["moment"]; 
        ?>
        <img src="images/<?php echo $moment; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
    </div>
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

**css**

```
body{
    color: black;
}

p{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d2y46u05/

right now it shows like this:
[image: example]

but the text should be like this, so In the middle of the image instead of the top of the page itself:
[image: example2]

Comment: Dropping loads of PHP code into a JSfiddle doesn’t make much sense. Replace that with the actually rendered HTML code at least. (And an image that actually loads in that context, otherwise this is rather worthless as a “live example” to begin with.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CSS has an attribute called `text-align`, which has a possible value for `center`. This is what you need, please check the snippet below, where I ensured that this styling is inside a `class` that has the attribute.

```css
body{
    color: black;
}

p{
    font-size: 32px;
}

.tac {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site2.css">
    <title>PHP time based page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="images">
      <div class="center">
        <p class="tac">Good Morning</p>
        <p class="tac">The time is 9:00 AM</p>
      </div>
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How has this been marked as the answer? It doesn't even do what he wanted! He wants to vertically and horizontally centre the text over an image

Comment: @CIB take a look at the question. It has CSS rules as attempts to solve the issue, where margin-left and margin-right are tried. So the centralization is meant horizontally. As about it's not being on an image, you have a point, that is, the image is below the centralized text, however, it seems that the answer was good-enough as a starting point to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `<p><?php echo getGreeting(); ?></p>` & `<?php $moment = getTime()["moment"]; ?>` in it's own div.

Then use flex or position absolute to centre

```
<div class="images">
    <div class="center">
        <p><?php echo getGreeting(); ?></p>
        <?php $moment = getTime()["moment"];  ?>
    </div>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $moment; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
</div>
```

```
.center {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 10;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I understand what youre doing here by wrapping the elements, but with this method the text still wont move

Comment: Why won't it move? https://codepen.io/craig_codes/pen/bGBRwrK

Comment: I have no idea why it wont move, i dont get an error or anything

Comment: Dump the raw HTML in your js fiddle and I'll take a look.

Comment: I did add the raw html to the js fiddle

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to set the hight of the image also. user ```object-fit: cover``` to stop the image from looking squashed. Also set a width and height on your images container.

Comment: i for real dont get it anymore. when i put it in  the jsfiddle then it work but however when i put it in my actual code it doesnt

Comment: Never mind,.it works now thanks. something went wrong with the linking of my css at the end

Answer (score 0):

you should add `position: absolute;` to your paragraph and then position it with the width and height property

if it is not working you should giv both elements a `z-index:  ;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `absolute` position for image, `flexbox` for the content to center align the text.

```css
body {
  color: black;
}

p {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.images img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site2.css">
  <title>PHP time based page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="images">
    <div class="center">
      <p>Good Morning</p>
      <p>The time is 9:00 AM</p>
    </div>
    <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900" alt="<?php echo $moment; ?>">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```